# Toyota Avensis - Day Running Lights are cutting off

Tags: toyota, lights, avensis

**Toyota Avensis 2012, T27, TR grade, 2.2 Diesel D4-D**

Couple of days ago I had a headlight out. So I went and bought another bulb, changed it - fine, all good. Then on the same day when I was getting fuel, I have noticed in the window reflection that my DRLs are not working. DRLs in this car are combination of a smaller than headlight bulb to the side of it and a LED stripe. They should always come on automatically, but yo can also switch them on by yourself. So this is what happens when I switch them on: http://sendvid.com/jzqtg6jr
As you can see the stripe is flashing for literally a second and then it cuts off. It's the same on both sides.

I checked the bulbs for the DRLs - they are both fine. I also checked the fuses, no issue there either. I'm not that experienced car user to look passed that, hence I need some help to see where should I go from here.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Since both sides are cutting out, this to me would mean an electrical issue. Intermittent issues are the worst! I'm not sure if these are controlled by a relay or not. This might be one failing (gets hot and quits sending juice). A relay for these would most likely be in the underhood fuse box. You'd have to change it out with another one to see if it continues to do the same thing.